# Running ASP.net under Mono Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I am currently investigating changing my Web server from windows to linux. I currently have an asp.net program that runs on my site and I want to try and get this working on Linux under mono.

I have copied over all of the files from my Windows server to my test linux server but when I try to access the page I get the following error:

> Unrecognised attributed 'requestValidationMode'
>   (/srv/www/htdocs/mywebsitedirectory/web.config

Below is a copy of web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DownloadManagerDB" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=downloads;Uid=public;Pwd=54mCuw90;pooling=false;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="16384" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /></assemblies></compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It looks as if on the error page Mono thinks its its asp.net version 2 when it is actually set to .net 4. I'm using mono version 2.10.6 which says that it supports .net 4.

Thanks for any  help you can provide.

**UPDATED:**
Output from running `ps auxwww | grep mono`

> wwwrun   12029  0.0  0.8  48800  8100 ?        Ssl  19:55   0:00
>   /usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mod-mono-server2.exe --filename
>   /tmp/mod_mono_server_global --nonstop --master root     12177  0.0 
>   0.0   2524   768 pts/1    S+   20:04   0:00 grep --color=auto mono

Comment: Did you install mod-mono-server2 (but not mod-mono-server4) by accident?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. When I look in yast I only see apache2-mod_mono. I've ran the upgrade for OpenSuse according to the instructions provided by Mono. But it still doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Run `ps auxwww | grep mono` and post!

Comment: I've updated the question content with the output from the command

Comment: I am not (better: no longer) familiar with the proceedings in SUSE, but you are running `mod-mono-server2.exe`and not `mod-mono-server4.exe`, in essence ASP.NET 2.0 not ASP.NET 4.0 - I can't help you with yast, my SUSE times are years over, but you can now rephrase your question and maybe post it in the SUSE forums: "How do I enable mod-mono-server4.exe instead of mod-mono-server2.exe for my SUSE installation?"

Answer (score 3):

Like @Eugen Rieck pointed out, you need to configure mod-mono-server4 instead of server2.

Following this article,

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Running-Orchard-on-Mono?Code=1

you should go to your Apache setting, and change MonoServerPath to /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4 (or the valid path on your box) Then you can test again to see if this attribute can be handled properly.